# Iterate directory without joining file with dir (os.join)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if there is a package that lets me avoid typing the `os.path.join` every time I'm opening a file, and have the handler already contain this info.

From this:

```
import os
top = '~/folder'
for file in os.listdir(top):
    full_file_path = os.path.join(top, file)
```

To:

```
import package
top = '~/folder'
for file in package.listdir(top):
    full_file_path = file
```

Comment: I think you might need to expand the tilde `~` in the path too - not sure if that's right though.

Comment: `pathlib` provides an alternative to `os.listdir` that makes this unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: I recommend **option 2**

### Option 1: A potential quick and dirty approach:

If your goal is to then open the files and you don't want to have to join, a trick could be to change your working directory:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/folder'))

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # do something with file
```

note that `file` will not contain the full path to your file, but since you changed your local dir (equiv do `cd`), you will be able to access the file with just its name.

### Option 2: Cleaner approach - pathlib:

Aside from that, you can also look into `pathlib` which is a module that provides nice path utilities.

For example:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path('~/folder').expanduser()

for file in path.glob('*'):
    # do something with file
```

So you get a better idea:

```
In [23]: path = pathlib.Path('~/Documents').expanduser()
In [24]: [i for i in path.glob('*')]
Out[24]: 
[PosixPath('/home/smagnan/Documents/folder1'),
 PosixPath('/home/smagnan/Documents/folder2'),
 PosixPath('/home/smagnan/Documents/file1')]
```

Comment: `os.chdir('~/folder')` will fail with a FileNotFoundError unless you have a directory literally named `~`. `os.path.expanduser()` will replace the `~` with a valid directory name.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! Didn't know about that, I usually stick with `pathlib`

Comment: ...you also need to do the same with `pathlib.Path`; check `pathlib.Path('~').exists()` and you'll see it's `False`. Though there there's an `expanduser()` method to do the transform in place, so `pathlib.Path('~').expanduser().exists()` is under sane conditions `True`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, was just testing that quick on my machine and noticed the issue as glob would just return nothing. Thx!

Comment: `path.glob('*')` maybe should just be `p.iterdir()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias to simplify the usage of a function:

```py
J = os.path.join

## -or- ##

import from os :: path.join as J


J(top, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define an alias on your import:

```
from os.path import join as pjoin
```

Or simply import it with `from ... import`, though `join` is a bit overloaded as a term, given it's implication for strings.

```
from os.path import join
```